# Remove trailing space when CSS pseudo-element ::after is not at the end of line

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

When my `::after` element is added in the middle of a line and not at the end, a trailing white space is added. I try to remove it.

By putting the element in inline-block is does remove the white space but then the height is changed too and I would like to prevent this.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```css
.test {
  
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 3px;
  z-index: 100 !important;
}

.test::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  background: var(--color);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-10deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-10deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
p {
  font-size : 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app" style="font-size: 24px; padding: 10px">

#1 <span class="test" :style="'z-index: 100;--color:' + '#ff00ff' + ';'">
    test
  </span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
#2 In a  <span class="test" :style="'z-index: 100;--color:' + '#ff00ff' + ';'">
    test
  </span> sentence.  





<p>
<br>
  <br>
In case #1 after element is at the end of the line and does not add a space.
<br>
<br>
<br>
In case #2 the element is in the middle of the line and add unwanted trailing space.
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Both pink boxes are indentical to me.

Comment: I tried with both firefox and chrome and i have a trailing space at the end of #2.

Comment: Looking in firefox both #1 and #2 have a space after `test` inside the pink box. In chrome #1 doesn't.

Comment: this is weird. What are your versions ?

Comment: Firefox 72, Chrome 80 (both on macOS 10.15.3)

Comment: I don't see any big height changing when making them inline-block

Comment: In the context of my css it does because the text is in a div that has a big height.

Answer (score 1):

its the line break in the HTML. when I delete the line break after between the text and the `</span>` it seems to work

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 3px;
  z-index: 100 !important;
}

.test::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  background: var(--color);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-10deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-10deg);
  /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app" style="font-size: 24px; padding: 10px">

  #1 <span class="test" :style="'z-index: 100;--color:' + '#ff00ff' + ';'">
    test
  </span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> #2 In a <span class="test" :style="'z-index: 100;--color:' + '#ff00ff' + ';'">test</span> sentence.





  <p>
    <br>
    <br> In case #1 after element is at the end of the line and does not add a space.
    <br>
    <br>
    <br> In case #2 the element is in the middle of the line and add unwanted trailing space.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is a solution but it's not a perfect one. I would want to cancel out this behavior.

Comment: there no straight forward solution. when you do a line break in HTML it registers as space. it doesn't matter how much spaces comes after it, it will register one space. so when there is a linebreak/space before the span closes, it will have the text "test ". and based on those characters/width the style will implement.

Comment: This renders a space after `test` in #1, but not in #2.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this (at least visually). So in my solution the leading and trailing space is still there but visually it's not shown.
So no need of having the content directly between `<li>`/`</li>` without a newline:

```
<ul class="comma-list">
  <li>
    Item 1
  </li>
  <li>Item 2
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS code will look like this:

```
ul.comma-list {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  gap: 0.2em;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul.comma-list li {
  display: inline-flex;
}
ul.comma-list li:after {
  content: ", ";
}
ul.comma-list li:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}
```

So basically it will remove all spaces and a a gap using inline flexbox.